# How to pass some parameters from Vbscript to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vbscript

I have an existing VBScript program.

I would like to know that is there have a way to send some parameters like name[string],age[int] and object from VBScript to display them on WPF(C#) window.

Answer (score 0):

That's a very open question.  I would suggest you look at creating a WCF service in your WCP application.
This will create an access point for other applications to send messagse to you WCP application.
Assuming these two applications are on the same machine then you should use a named pipes binding for the best performance.

The service call would tigger some text to be diplayed on the screen.

I'm not sure how you would connect to this from VBScript, but I'ld imagine google knows.

Comment: Hi Buh Buh, actually I want something like this (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/46a01531-a140-4b8f-954a-34628ada1e53)  but all I need is to pass the parameter to WPF Window directly instead of library\

Comment: on the other hand, I would like to know that how to create WPF(C#) program that be able like ActiveX EXE as vb6